# Remove indexing from matrix in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a barplot for which I need my data in a matrix.  I have made some really nice plots before when my matrix looked like this:

```
       0%   20%   40%   60%  80%
C2   0.22  0.94  1.66  2.38 3.10
CC  -1.38 -0.66  0.06  0.79 1.51
CCW -1.61 -0.87 -0.13  0.62 1.36
P   -1.13 -0.16  0.81  1.78 2.76
PF   0.03  0.72  1.42  2.11 2.80
S2  -2.34 -1.61 -0.88 -0.16 0.57
```

For the rest of my data, I had to convert it from a dataframe, which I did using as.matrix(df).  This matrix looks like this:

```
     trt   2009     2010      2011     
[1,] "C2"  "9.0525" " 8.1400" " 8.1400"
[2,] "CC"  "5.4200" " 4.7975" " 4.7975"
[3,] "CCW" "4.9675" " 4.0400" " 4.0400"
[4,] "P"   "9.3150" "10.3500" "10.3500"
[5,] "PF"  "9.0950" " 3.3375" " 3.3375"
[6,] "S2"  "3.1725" " 3.1125" " 3.1125"
```

It won't work with the barplot function.  I think I need to remove the index column, but haven't been able to.  And what is with the quotes?  I though a matrix was a matrix, so I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: `as.matrix(yourdata[,-1])`.  Because your first column is non-numeric (character or factor), and the columns of matrices have to be all the same types, `as.matrix` is coercing all the data to be characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quotes means your `matrix` is in mode `character`. This is because `matrix`, as opposed to `data.frame` which are superficially similar, can only hold one type. Because alphanumeric characters cannot be converted to numeric, your matrix is in mode `character`. I would be easier to remove the first column before converting it to `matrix` and save yourself of converting the matrix to `numeric`.

```
m <- as.matrix(df[, -1])

#To add the row.names.

row.names(m) <- df[, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, Luciano!  That makes sense and your fix worked like a charm.